# Ruby on RAils (rubyweaver) dreamweaver cs5 integrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I saw there is an dreamweaver called rubyweaver.  Does anyone know of plans to upgrade that to CS5?  anyone hear interested in doing this?  It would be helpful for newbies like me to have some Wysiwyg editing.  Any other software offer that for ruby on rails?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rubyweaver](http://rubyweaver.js-designz.net/) site they are not offering CS5 support due to not having a developer that can perform the update work for the extension. This appears to be due to the site that is offering the download of Rubyweaver is not the same people that developed the original extension.

You may want to try the extension out, some of the functionality of it may work in CS5. The site doesn't list any specific CS5 issues on it [Known Issues](http://rubyweaver.js-designz.net/?page_id=9) page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that we do not currently have a developer for this extension as of yet. We have a few potential prospects that we are currently having talks with. The Original Creator of the extension is Rob Cameron of RidingTheClutch.com. Jason Gills took over the IDE and updated it to it's latest state.

We took over the RubyWeaver IDE from the Jason Gills as he was not able to provide the extension or keep up with the development of RubyWeaver, so we got with Jason and decided to keep this extension available to everyone.

We hope to be offering an updated version as soon as we find a coder.

I hope this information helps out.

Thank You,

John

Comment: Rob here: someone commented on my blog the other day saying they couldn't find Rubyweaver anymore. I found the original code on an old harddrive and put it up on GitHub: https://github.com/cannikin/rubyweaver If there's newer code somewhere please let me know and I can can link over to that or merge it into mine via pull request.